# How to add a facebook and google login button without creating app id?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. And I am designing a webvsite that needs the social login buttons.
I have found some plugins, and also used the developers.facebook.com login button, but it is not working with my localhost server. I have also used the Like button from the same site. and
it is working properly.
Same problem is happening with google+. Am I missing something?

Please reply soon..
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement social login w/o appID in it's services, it's public but not transparent.

To enable social login you will need a valid callback URL, so app will know where to redirect user after successful auth. This part is pain in the ass, because you don't have domains at development stage. Plus you will need to configure cookies / sessions to handle authentication at valid domain scope.

If you want to properly configure oAuth or other auth service - do it on isolated production server.

Comment: thanks for your reply! But does my problem will solve just by editing the callback URL.